# How _ast.py is generated in CPython

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, cpython

Python `ast` module relies on `_ast.py` to define all specific AST nodes. By inspecting the file, it appears it is a generated file (as of 3.8):

```
# encoding: utf-8
# module _ast
# from (built-in)
# by generator 1.147
```

I would like to inspect the source code of the generator creating this file in [CPython code](https://github.com/python/cpython), but I can't find it. I have tried searching the source for `_ast`, `1.147`, `generator *. ast` and other searches with no success.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218509/find-out-elements-of-ast-module-which-is-imported-in-ast-py

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/Python-ast.c#L8793) and [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/Python-ast.c#L1)